# External connections from PHP/Apache max-out server resources. How to deal with this?

Tags: php, apache

I am connecting to an external service (ex. Algolia) from my PHP backend. Say, the external service takes a while to respond (ex. >1 sec). During that duration, the Apache process keeps waiting on it and is unable to complete the request.

Further incoming traffic on the website causes Apache to start forking more processes because the previously forked processes are still waiting for the request to be completed.

In the worst case, if I get too many simultaneous requests to the same URL which was invoking that external service, a lot of Apache processes go into waiting state ultimately causing the server CPU load to sky-rocket and the Ubuntu server to completely stop responding.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Are you routing the search queries to Algolia through your apache server? Or these waiting processes are adding records to the index? Ideally you should be connecting to Algolia directly from the browser for queries and the indexing call should be make in a worker

Comment: Yeah, but this is just an example. The same problem occurs with every third party service we connect to.

Comment: oh ok! I dont have an idea about Apache server. But ya this is unusual behaviour